# How to check if a table exist before creating

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am setting up database from a remote database using the dblink

here are my scripts to create table and constraints..

```
 begin 
     
  dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement@mydblink('CREATE TABLE MYTABLE1
   (ID NUMBER(5,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE , 
    CODE NVARCHAR2(15), 
    DESCRIPTION NVARCHAR2(125), 
    IS_ACTIVE NUMBER(1,0)   DEFAULT 1
   )') ;
   
  dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement@mydblink('CREATE UNIQUE INDEX MYTABLE1_PK ON MYTABLE1 (ID) 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)');
  
   end;
```

i would like to check if table exist before creating them and drop the table if it exist. How can we achieve this.mydblink is the dblink used to connect to a database from a remote database

How to check if a tables/constraint exist and drop them all.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
declare
v_cnt number;
v_sql varchar2(100);
begin 
    select count(*) into v_cnt from user_tables where table_name = 'ABC';

    if v_cnt=0 then

      v_sql:='create table abc(col1 number)';
      dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);
      execute immediate v_sql;
end if;

end;
```

Comment: Hi , you could do it by capturing the table ORA-00955 in the Error handler, if the table exists. Please check this link for an example.   https://database.guide/2-ways-to-create-a-table-if-it-doesnt-already-exist-in-oracle/